# How to add ignorefiles for specific rules in stylelint config js

Tags: javascript, csslint, stylelint

Hi want to ignore certain files for a specific rule in style lint config js like below

```
'color-named': [
        'never', {
            'ignore': [ 'library/styles/**/*.css', 'components/**/styles/variable.css' ]
        }
    ],
```

However this is not working, Any suggetions how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `ignore` configuration option which accepts globs in stylelint.

I believe you have two choices:

1. Add `/* stylelint-disable color-named */` to the beginning of the appropriate files ([ref](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/configuration.md#turning-rules-off-from-within-your-css)).
2. Create two separate configurations: one with the `color-named` rule turned on and one with it turned off. Then run stylelint twice with different globs, using the `--config` option to select the appropriate config. You can make use of *extendable configs* to remove duplication within the configs e.g. have a `base` config and a `strict` config that extends the `base` config and turns on the `color-named` rule ([ref](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/configuration.md#rules)).